# expo how i read an image

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker

I successfully uploaded an image with imagepicker and multer to my folder "uploads/".

I also send the filename back to the client:

```
res.send({uploadedImage: req.file.path});
// Result:
Object {
  "uploadedImage": "uploads\\photo_1619350900261_b1099740-f86c-4809-ae62-0ad973a499c0.jpg",
}
```

So how can I now read the file or the image? I can put this in a state but there is no url in this image object upload.

Comment: Base url is your server url where you get data from

Comment: you mean http://myserverurl.de/req.file.path <- like this?

Comment: Yes but without req.file.path

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. The image is not showing with that url, and If I enter this url in chrome then I get can not get ... (nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

To Display the image from response

Use it like this

`BaseURL` = The URL at which you send post requests (i.e, your Backend Server)

`Result.uploadedImage` = This you get from the response

So the final uri would be

`uri` = BaseURL + Result.uploadedImage

It will look Something like this `localhost:3000/uploads\\photo_1619350900261_b1099740-f86c-4809-ae62-0ad973a499c0.jpg` or `127.0.0.1:3000/uploads\\photo_1619350900261_b1099740-f86c-4809-ae62-0ad973a499c0.jpg`

But if you are working on your phone then you might have to replace your BaseURL with your IPv4 address.. This address you can get it from CMD

1.) Open CMD

2.) type `ipconfig`

3.) Scroll down and look for `IPv4 Address`..It will look something like this
`192.168.100.74`

4.) Now `uri_to_display` = `IPv4 Address + : + PORT + Result.uploadedImage`